# Banco Consumindo toda memoria

Tags: sql, sql-server, desempenho

Bom dia estou com um problema , os usuários de um determinado sistema estão com problemas na hora de consultar um nome no sistema "uma pesquisa simples" , entrei no banco e notei que no sql tem vários bancos e um deles que não o do sistema que os usuários reclama esta consumindo 97% do total de memoria RAM do meu servidor , ele esta sempre assim não importa a hora ou quantas pessoas estão usando, gostaria de saber se isso esta errado  e se tem algo que eu possa fazer segue os dados[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: precisa de mais informação antes de até dar uma direção. A primeira coisa que eu diria é fazer um profile e identificar se alguma query está fazendo com que o banco consuma tanta memória, as vezes um aparentemente inocente `OR` ou um campo null fazem estragos. Verifique primeiro se um query está causando isso, e se não for, dá pra idetificar os processos, mas sugiro começar por ai

Comment: como eu teria que proceder para verificar as query e ver o tanto que elas estão consumindo , desculpa a falta de informação mais sou desenvolverdor junior e nunca tive que controlar banco desse jeito , antes quem fazia isso era um dba

Answer (score 1):

Abra o SQL Management Studio, conecte-se ao servidor que ocupa toda a memória, com um usuário administrador.

Clique com o direito sobre o servidor na janela Object Explorer e selecione Propriedades.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ajuste a memória e clique em OK.

Comment: muito obrigado marcelo , sera que isso pode dar algum problema de lentidão no banco que esta ocupando muita memoria ou sera que ele esta ocupando essa memoria sem necessidade . pq atem nos finais de semana que não tem nenhum usuario ele fica desse jeito

Comment: O normal do SQL Server *é* alocar toda a memória disponível. Se você diminuir os valores na instrução que te passei, ele vai alocar menos.

Comment: obrigado Marcelo novamente

Comment: Não há de quê, @FlavioSs!